# Android Studio: Buildtools 24.0.1 requires Java 1.8 or above.

Tags: java, android, macos, android-studio

I'm trying to setup an Android dev environment on Mac.

My starting point is Java 1.7 I believe. So I installed android studio and opened the project I'd like to build. And it says:

```
Error:Buildtools 24.0.1 requires Java 1.8 or above.  Current JDK version is 1.7.
```

So I went and download Java 1.8 u101 and installed that. No luck. Then I removed Android Studio and re-installed it and re-installed the SDK and still no luck.

My Java Control Pannel says: Java 8 update 101. 
Output of `/usr/bin/java`:

```
java version "1.8.0_101"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)
```

Output of `/usr/bin/javac`

```
javac 1.8.0_101
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: change project  jdk location (Project structure->sdk location)

Comment: I am facing exactly the same issue on Windows 7.

Comment: So does Android now support Java 8?

Comment: Thanks it worked !

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Make sure your **JDK Version through Project Structure**

[image]

You can add this in your gradle section

```
    compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }
```

Comment: I'm using Mac. Not sure if it's the same.

Answer (score 3):

On a Mac just double-click on the app and a new modal windows will show. Then select *'Open Module Setting'* and go to *'SDK Location'*.

Answer (score 0):

Click **project structure -> app -> in properties change the (compile Sdk Version ) to google API's 23** . and in build tools Version = **22.0.1**