# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions i tried all but solution but i dont know solution

Tags: android, gradle, firebase

How to resolve problem? I'm used everything. This is duplicate but I tried all.

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

I'm using `multiDexEnable = true` also

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
  }

dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
  }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
  maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

android {
  compileSdkVersion 23
  buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.agilerise.school"
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 3
    versionName "1.3"
    enforceUniquePackageName = false
    multiDexEnabled true
  }
  buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),  'proguard-rules.pro'
        resValue "string", "google_maps_api_key",  "AIzaSyCPkzR0YESTkV97RaMW0iJvgxuW_2EpfPI"
    }
    debug {
        resValue "string", "google_maps_api_key", "AIzaSyD-rVHRsXJJFcThPFRgyBwKok3qXggMxtM"
    }

  }
  dexOptions {
    incremental true
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
  }
}

dependencies {
  compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
  compile files('libs/gcm.jar')
  compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'

  compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
  compile                                                   'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
  compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'

  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.0.1'

  compile 'com.jpardogo.googleprogressbar:library:1.2.0'
  compile 'com.github.traex.rippleeffect:library:1.3'
  compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
  compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'

  compile 'com.daimajia.easing:library:1.0.1@aar'
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
  compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:1.1.3@aar'
  compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.5@aar') {
    transitive = true;
  }
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

See PlayService

[image: See PlayService]

Comment: Please refer this link to setup firebase [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup).
In your gradle file you dont have to load full playservice repository.
For eg. compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'

Comment: how to load singale paly store library i m using google map in my app

Comment: have your updated your play services?

Comment: see this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37360126/getting-exception-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-firebase-firebaseop

Comment: yes revice version is 38

Comment: @sourabh have you followed the above link?

Comment: @sourabh Do check link which is mentioned in my comment, their is a proper guide to intigrate play service and how to load package which you want to use like map, ads etc.

Comment: Hi i think you have not installed google play service package in sdk?

Answer (score 1):

Add the classpath to `build.gradle`.

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Error:(11, 0) Cause: com/android/build/gradle/AppPlugin : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
<a href="openFile:C:\android project\school connect\app\build.gradle">Open File</a>

Comment: after aply this line

Comment: Your android studio is not updated...already nougat is out and you target SDK is  marshmallow (23)...I think firebase also requires gradle 2 atleast...why don't you update your android studio first

Comment: @sourabh  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39116095/android-studio-buildtools-24-0-1-requires-java-1-8-or-above/39116275#39116275

Answer (score 0):

use following dep in gradle

```
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.0'
```

Comment: you don't need to add playservices to dependencies