# How do I resolve: "Error evaluating project ':app'.Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Tags: java, android

I have tried to really research this error and I can't seem to find a fix.

I upgraded my android studios and I am receiving the following error:

> Error:(1, 1) A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
>
> > java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/build/gradle/AppPlugin : Unsupported major.minor version
> >     52.0

I cannot run a basic hello world program. I don't know if my gradle is messed up or if I am having java problems.

I am running:

Android Studios 2.3.1

Java Version 8 Update 101 (build 1.8.0_101-b13)

Windows 8

How would I go about resolving this error? Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35937875/unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0-when-rendering-in-android-studio/38503342#38503342

Comment: at first make sure using 1.8 or not http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39116095/android-studio-buildtools-24-0-1-requires-java-1-8-or-above/39116275#39116275

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to go to File > Project Structure

In the JDK location, I had to change the path to: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101

It built without any errors.

Comment: Yes, I was just spelling it out to make it easier if someone comes across this post.

Comment: Thank you for resolving my error. I got my error resolved by changing `jdk7` to `jdk8`

Answer (score 2):

inside the "Project Structure" settings window
 enabled the "Use embedded JDK (recommended)" 
 in the SDK location tab