# Apply plugin com.android.application failed

Tags: android, gradle

The gradle fails to build with the following error message:

> /home/researcher/.android/build-cache.lock
>   Open File

Run build error:

> org.gradle.initialization.ReportedException: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Build file '/home/researcher/AndroidStudioProjects/EmApp/app/build.gradle' line: 1
>   A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
>       at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:139)
>       at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.getConfiguredBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:104)
>       at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$2.call(GradleBuildController.java:87)
>   .......

and much more. 
I couldn't exactly figure out what is wrong and why this happens.

This is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.researcher.emapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}`
```

Please help me fix this problem.

Edit1: Deleting home/researcher/.android/build-cache.lock can't be done as there's no such file in .android
The ls command:

`researcher@researcher1:~$ cd /home/researcher/.android
researcher@researcher1:~/.android$ ls
adbkey  adbkey.pub  uid.txt`

I have pointed out to the installed jdk as mentioned in 
[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43464116/how-do-i-resolve-error-evaluating-project-app-unsupported-major-minor-versi) , But in vain. Please help me fix this issue. Thanks:)

Comment: Delete /home/researcher/.android/build-cache.lock file and restart build.

Comment: @AkshayMahajan there's no such file in .android

Comment: `researcher@researcher1:~$ cd /home/researcher/.android
researcher@researcher1:~/.android$ ls
adbkey  adbkey.pub  uid.txt
`